# cherryPy callback after response has been served

Tags: python, tornado, cherrypy

I am trying to call a function after receiving output from my application. I can do the same with a sample function `func()` in Tornado as follows:

```
def func():
    print("hello")

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")
        self.finish()
        func()

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

How can i do the same in cherryPy?

Comment: Exactly the same thing cannot be done in cherryPy. But you can emulate it by running the function in a separate thread. You could use some process/thread pool or even message broker (e.g. RabbitMQ) for that depending on your needs.

Comment: Also, you can use CherryPy plugins (like BackgroundProcess)